# Why is the inverse of a bounded bijective operator continuous?

Tags: open-map

I'm facing some troubles with the following theorem,

Let $X,Y$ be Banach spaces and let $T \in B(X,Y)$. I want to show that if $T$ is bijective then its inverse is continuous. Now if $T$ is bijective than its surjectivity implies that it is open by the open mapping theorem. From here on I need do deduce that $T^{-1}$ is continuous but I don't see it really.

Can someone help me with this?

thanks in advance

Comment: It appears you're looking for a proof of the [bounded inverse theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounded_inverse_theorem).

Comment: The fact that a bijective function $f$ between topological spaces has continuous inverse if and only if it is open is an exercise of general topology. It really uses nothing but the definitions.